# Сортировка по штрафам в массиве через рокировки

Tags: php, сортировка

такая проблема: никак не пойму как сделать реализацию сортировки по штрафам, при этом по бонусам сделать получилось.

**Дано:** двумерный массив пользователей, у каждого есть id, имя, стартовая позиция и модификатор (если отрицательный то бонус, если положительный то штраф).

**Как работают бонусы:** например, есть очередь из пользователей Test1, Test2, Test3. Если пользователю Test3 прописать бонус 1, то он поменяется местами с пользователем Test2 и получится Test1, Test3, Test2. Если поставить бонус 2, то он станет первым.

Штрафы работают наоборот. Если пользователю Test1 прописать штраф 3, он переместится в конец очереди.

Вот мой работающий код для бонусов:

```
<?
$new = array(); $orders = array();

$new[111]['position'] = 1; $new[111]['user'] = 'Test1'; $orders[1] = 111; $new[111]['shift'] = 0;
$new[222]['position'] = 2; $new[222]['user'] = 'Test2'; $orders[2] = 222; $new[222]['shift'] = 0;
$new[333]['position'] = 3; $new[333]['user'] = 'Test3'; $orders[3] = 333; $new[333]['shift'] = 0;
$new[444]['position'] = 4; $new[444]['user'] = 'Test4'; $orders[4] = 444; $new[444]['shift'] = 0;
$new[555]['position'] = 5; $new[555]['user'] = 'Test5'; $orders[5] = 555; $new[555]['shift'] = 0;
$new[666]['position'] = 6; $new[666]['user'] = 'Test6'; $orders[6] = 666; $new[666]['shift'] = 0;
$new[777]['position'] = 7; $new[777]['user'] = 'Test7'; $orders[7] = 777; $new[777]['shift'] = 0;
$new[888]['position'] = 8; $new[888]['user'] = 'Test8'; $orders[8] = 888; $new[888]['shift'] = 0;


//функция для сдвига
function bonus($start, $bonus)
{
  global $new, $orders;
  //для бонусов, сдвиг в начало, $bonus отрицательное число
  if ($bonus < 0)
  {
    for ($i = $start; $i > ($start - abs($bonus)); $i--)
    {
      $order_id = intval($orders[$i]);
      $prev = intval($orders[$i - 1]);
      if ($prev != 0)
      {
        $temp = $new[$order_id]['position'];
        $new[$order_id]['position'] = $new[$prev]['position'];
        $new[$prev]['position'] = $temp;
        $orders[$i] = $prev;
        $orders[$i - 1] = $order_id;
      }
    }

  }
  //конец для бонусов
}

//Задаю вручную штрафы (бонусы отрицательные, штрафы положительные)
$new[555]['shift'] = -2;

//сортирую по бонусам
$i = 1;
foreach($new as $value)
{
  $order_id = $orders[$i];
  bonus($new[$order_id]['position'], $new[$order_id]['shift']);
  $i++;
}

  //сортировка двумерного массива по полю позиция
  usort($new, function($a, $b){
      return $a['position'] <=> $b['position'];
  });

//ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ

$i = 1;
foreach($new as $value)
{
 echo $i . '. ' . $value['user'] . ' ; сдвиг: ' . $value['shift'];
 echo '<br>';
 $i++;
}

?>
```

Здесь бонус задаётся через $new[555]['shift'] = -2;

Соответственно, штраф будет выглядеть как $new[444]['shift'] = 3;

Код для штрафов вроде бы должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
//для штрафов, сдвиг в конец, $bonus положительное число
  if ($bonus > 0)
  {
    $total_new = count($new);
    for ($i = $start; $i < ($start + $bonus); $i++)
    {
      $order_id = intval($orders[$i]);
      $next = intval($orders[$i + 1]);
      if ($next < $total_new)
      {
        $temp = $new[$order_id]['position'];
        $new[$order_id]['position'] = $new[$next]['position'];
        $new[$next]['position'] = $temp;
        $orders[$i] = $next;
        $orders[$i + 1] = $order_id;
      }
    }
  }
  //конец для штрафов
```

Только менять массив $orders надо как-то по-другому. Я попробовал много разных вариаций, включая проход массива наоборот, с конца, но корректной работы не добился...

Answer (score 0):

Приведите структуру массива в порядок, тогда сортировать можно будет без "соток/гектар" ненужного кода.

```
$new = [
    '111' => [
        'position' => 1,
        'user'     => 'Test1',
        'shift'    => 0
    ],
    '222' => [
        'position' => 2,
        'user'     => 'Test2',
        'shift'    => 0
    ],
    '333' => [
        'position' => 3,
        'user'     => 'Test2',
        'shift'    => 0
    ]
];

$new[111]['shift'] = -3;

array_multisort(array_column($new, 'shift'), SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $new);
```

[чек](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8f1fe89f7c89fec292b676e579272f06d8f09bd)

[магия array_multysort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: вообще не то, вы прочитали мой вопрос полностью? Мне нужна смена элементов через рокировки, а не сортировка по полю. Если я использую array_multisort, он просто отсортирует элементы местами по значению, а мне нужно сдвинуть элемент определённое количество раз. На 5 элементах, например, сдвиг на 1 вашим кодом отправит Test1 в самый конец https://pastebin.com/GbW4zywb

Comment: Штрафы работают наоборот. Если пользователю Test1 прописать штраф 3, он переместится в конец очереди. - это ж вы написали? И если вы подразумеваете какую-то определённую логику при перемещении элементов по массиву, то я не увидел её описание, пардонте.

Comment: извините, вероятно формулировка ввела в заблуждение. Должно быть так: не в конец очереди, а на 3 места дальше (что тоже будет концом очереди при трёх участниках). Другими словами, если у меня в очереди 5 элементов, то при штрафе 3 первый элемент станет четвёртым. Т.е. задача именно чтобы элементы менялись местами.

Comment: А, ещё добавлю, что реализация через баллы мне не подходит (т.е. если каждому участнику начислить баллов в соответствии с его стартовой позицией, а потом эти баллы корректировать через бонус/штраф), потому что тогда при штрафе в единицу его баллы станут равны баллам следующего в очереди, и по-сути порядок в очереди не поменяется.

Comment: А как сортируются участники впринципе? по shift или position? Баллы - это shift?

Comment: Да, баллы это shift (он англ. сдвиг). На самом деле у меня есть поля bonus и penalty, а shift = penalty - bonus, но я сократил для простоты). Поле shift в функции я определил как $bonus. Участники сортируются в начале по position, потом мы перебираем массив и по каждому участнику делаем несколько циклов сдвигов position (в зависимости от из значения меняем пользователей местами), а в конце сортируем по этим новым position и выводим.